# Troubles interpreting steps to create program

Tags: python

my question asks me to display a menu with options on what to do to the loaded file. i should be able to calculate the minimum, maximum and sum of the chosen txt file. So i ask the user to type a filename to load ex Alpha.txt. A constriction set was that there must be equal amount of rows and columns of numbers 4x4, 5x5, 12x12, and so on. my code so far only factors in 4x4 rows and columns of numbers . Btw this is not homework, but rather practice problems for an upcoming quiz. I do NOT want a solution but rather just some help interpreting what i should do given the situation. I WANT to type my own code and learn so please do not think im asking for an answer. thanks! :)

goal table is supposed to look like this

```
-----------------------------------------------
|     |   A   |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E   |
-----------------------------------------------
|   1 | 8.00  | 1.00  | 3.00  | 0.00  | 5.00  |
|   2 | 5.00  | 6.00  | 8.00  | 9.00  | 4.00  |
|   3 | 3.10  | 3.20  | 3.30  | 9.10  | 3.30  |
-----------------------------------------------
```

and i should be able to calculate the desired choice based on column or row based on entered either a-z or 1-whatever number of column

```
def main():

    my_list = [[float(i) for i in line.split(',')] for line in open("Alpha.txt")]
    print(my_list)
    my_list_one = my_list[0]
    my_list_two = my_list[1]
    my_list_three = my_list[2]
    my_list_four = my_list[3]

    columnA = [my_list[0][0],my_list[1][0],my_list[2][0],my_list[3][0]]
    columnB = [my_list[0][1],my_list[1][1],my_list[2][1],my_list[3][1]]
    columnC = [my_list[0][2],my_list[1][2],my_list[2][2],my_list[3][2]]
    columnD = [my_list[0][3],my_list[1][3],my_list[2][3],my_list[3][3]]

    usrnput = input("Enter a row or column: ")
    if usrnput == 'A' or usrnput == 'a':
        print(min(columnA))
    elif usrnput == 'B' or usrnput == 'b':
        print(min(columnB))
    elif usrnput == 'C' or usrnput == 'c':
        print(min(columnC))
    elif usrnput == 'D' or usrnput == 'd':
        print(min(columnD))
    elif usrnput == "1":
        print(min(my_list_one))
    elif usrnput == "2":
        print(min(my_list_two))
    elif usrnput == "3":
        print(min(my_list_three))
    elif usrnput == "4":
        print(min(my_list_four))

main()
```

and alpha.txt contains

```
5,4,2,3.2
1,.2,4.4,8
3,8,6.5,2
3,2,1,5.3
```

Now my problem lies in that i obviously dont factor in the possibility anything but 4x4 which is bad. So in order to fix this i need to redo my code completely.

What i really am asking for is what is the human language interpretation of what i need to do? i want to convert that into pythonic code so i understand the concept better than just knowing the solution and say ah yeah i get that without actually doing it cause that will not help me for the quiz.

im pretty sure i can load the file if i just adjust the "Alpha.txt" part to a variable and have fo = open("userinput")

but how would i take a nested list i produce from the file and determine a min or max or sum of a column or row? i was thinking i should use len() and a count but it doesnt come together in my head or on paper. and i need to use a for loop for this instead of hardcoding each column as a new list and each row as a list like in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- names like `my_list_one` are useless - better use `my_list[0]`
- the same with `columnA` - better `column['A']` or `column[0]`
- `len(my_list)` give you how many rows you load from file
- `len(my_list[0])` give you how many columns you load from file
- if user input number ("1", "2") you can convert it from string to integer and use as index in `my_list[index]` (or `my_list[index-1]`)
- `usrnput.lower()` give lower letter and you don't have to compare it with big letter
- or you can use `if usrnput in ('a', 'A'):`
- use constructions like `for index in range(len(my_list)):` or `for row in my_list:` and `column['A'].append(some_value_from_my_list)` to create columns

**@EDIT:**

Full program (Python 3)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

def main():

    # read file

    all_rows = [[float(i) for i in line.split(',')] for line in open("Alpha.txt")]

    # table size

    rows_number = len(all_rows)
    cols_number = len(all_rows[0])

    print("size (rows x cols): {0}x{1}".format(rows_number,cols_number))
    print()

    # create columns (indexed by numbers)

    all_columns = []

    for col_index in range(cols_number):

        all_columns.append([])

        for row_index in range(rows_number):
            all_columns[col_index].append(all_rows[row_index][col_index])

    # print rows

    print("rows")

    for i,row in enumerate(all_rows):
        print(i+1, ":", " , ".join(str(num) for num in row))

    print()

    # print cols

    print("cols")

    for i, col in enumerate(all_columns):
        print(chr(ord('A')+i), ":", " , ".join(str(num) for num in col))

    print()

    # main loop

    end = False

    while not end:
        usrnput = input("Enter a row or column (or 'Q' for quit): ").upper()

        if usrnput in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L'):
            index = ord(usrnput)-ord('A')
            if index < cols_number:
                print("min", all_columns[index], "=", min(all_columns[index]))
        elif usrnput in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12'):
            index = int(usrnput)-1
            if index < rows_number:
                print("min", all_rows[index], "=", min(all_rows[index]))
        elif usrnput in ('Q'):
            end = True

main()
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the breakdown of what i can use! :). for calculating the max/min of a column how would i determine what is A-Z if the table is a variable based on the user txt file chosen?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using a loop and a dict to access the column (by letter) or the row (by number).

I would:

1. take your raw input and determine if it's a number/letter
2. If number, just grab that index of your list of lists
3. If letter, turn it into an int through a dict, and grab those indices from the sublists, and turn those into a list.

Then you can do whatever calculations you want on it after you have your returned list.

Comment: Thank you! i will report back with my code again using this suggestion :)

Comment: you can also turn it into a number by doing `ord(my_letter.upper())-ord('A')`